# File I/O across processes in Linux?

Tags: c++, file-io, filesystems, fork-join

So, I've got a Linux process where I'm trying to manage some files on a tape.  I have the following code that attempts to extract a file, catalog.xml, from the current archive on the tape and copy it to a fixed location (eventually, I'll parse the file and do some work with the results).  But, my code is intermittently failing to work correctly.  The tar command always succeeds, (and if I check the file system, I see the catalog.xml file), but sometimes my followup check to see if the file exists returns false.  Am I doing something obviously wrong?  It seems like I'm probably encountering a race condition between the fork()ed process returning and the results of that process being visible on the file system - is there some call I need to make?

```
  pid_t tPid = vfork();
  if (0 == tPid)
  {
    int tChildRet;
    tChildRet = execlp("tar", "tar", "-xvf", "/dev/nst0", "-C", "/tmp", "catalog.xml", (char *) 0);
    _exit(-1 == tChildRet ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  else
  {
    wait(&ret);
  }
std::ifstream tCatalogFile("/tmp/catalog.xml");
if (tCatalogFile)
{
   cout << "File exists!" << endl;
} else {
   cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
}
```

And I'm getting either "file exists!" or "file does not exist!", seemingly at random.

Other notes:
On the failure cases:

- if I do a `stat ("/tmp/catalog.xml")`, I get a return of -1 with errno set to ENOENT.
- the tar command (run with the -v flag) produces the expected one line of output ("catalog.xml")

/tmp is a local tmpfs filesystem; the tape drive is a local device.
I'm using 2.6.30.9 Linux kernel with g++ 4.1.2 on a x86_64 box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are other errors that can cause the open to fail (all dependent on the file system being used). More detail on the file system would be nice.

Comment: Note: it the execlp works then it will never return. So _exit() will only be called if execlp() fails. Also you do not check to see if the vfork() actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `execlp` succeeds, it will never get to the line where you call `_exit`. You aren't checking the return value (`ret`) from `wait`. It's not clear why you should be using `vfork`. Etc.

Since the parent is not doing anything else besides waiting for the child to complete, why not make your life easier and just use `system()`?

Comment: The _exit is to handle the case where execlp fails. I had the same thought about system, since the parameters are static and don't even need to be quoted.

Comment: The above code is somewhat simplified - there's a bit more error-checking, etc in my actual code base.  I didn't use system() because my program is run setuid (and system() is therefore insecure.)

Comment: I would also suggest `waitpid` and not `wait`; if you have another child process that exits while your code is running, `wait` would return its pid rather than the child you just spawned. Long and short of it, I have to agree with Emery - why not use `system` since you're really not doing anything else while you wait for the child process to finish?

Comment: Will - I think the waitpid vs wait is actually my answer.  I'm doing the same thing on multiple tape drives at a time using separate threads, and the failure seems to happen whenever the drive I'm looking at finishes its tar command second.  Thanks!

Comment: Accepted this answer, since the return value from wait would in fact have led me to the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try calling [`sync`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) after the `wait` call in the parent.

If that doesn't work, you may need to loop and/or sleep until the parent can open the file, since you know it's there.

Comment: So far, this appears to be working - thanks!  I'll report back once I've had a chance to test a little more thoroughly.

Comment: The other answer turned out to be the root cause - but the sync call did fix a related problem I had elsewhere.  Thanks again!